# Hello i am having trouble getting the location of this picture to show in my react project

Tags: html, reactjs

Its a JS File (FacePalm) I added the JSX curly braces but it still won't show up.
Here is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/y68h9oj3/
I am trying to add a picture to my react project but it will not show up I tried hosting the picture on a web server it works but when I use local directory the image does not show up.
C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Portfolio\Rework1\src Here is where the pictures location.

here is the src I have on the image tag

```
    <img src="src/Aboutme.png" alt="Aboutme Header"></img>
```

C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Portfolio\Rework1\src Here is where the pictures location.

```
    <img src="src/Aboutme.png" alt="Aboutme Header"></img>
```

I expected the image to show up

Comment: Can you post the contents of your JS file and HTML file? It will help others to better understand your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing your image and then use it with curly braces. Something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Refer https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files

Comment: can you physically move the image to a sub folder of your html file? and then use a relative path?